# How can reorder the factor by stat=summary result

Tags: r, ggplot2

These two produce the same graph. Great.

```
library(ggplot)
library(forcats)

ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=cut,y=price)) +
  geom_bar(stat="summary",fun=mean)

diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  summarize(mean_price = mean(price, na.rm = TRUE), count= n())  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cut,y=mean_price)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

My question is how do get the following graph without aggregating the data first (via `group_by` and `summarize`)

```
diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  summarize(mean_price = mean(price, na.rm = TRUE), count= n())  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=fct_reorder(cut,mean_price),y=mean_price)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `reorder` `cut` by `price`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = reorder(cut, price), y = price)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = mean) +
  xlab("cut")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves the problem. I'm curious, though, I had tried : ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = fct_reorder(cut, price), y = price)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = mean) +
  xlab("cut") and it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: @user23438 Try `fct_reorder(cut, price, .fun = mean)`, the default uses `median` as the summary function